# How to increase spacing between the end of contents of a section and title of succeeding section

Tags: html, css

How do I increase the spacing between the ending contents of  and the title of  from a CSS file? For instance consider the following part of a dumb webpage.

[image]

So for instance I would like to increase the spacing between the ending of Section 1 and the title of Section 2 as in the image above. What do I add to the CSS file to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can apply margin-bottom property to the section 1 or can apply margin-top to the title of section 2 like this:

```
.section1{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

or

```
.section2{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

add this style to your css file. Change margin's value according to how much space do you want. Apply margin-bottom to section 1 or apply margin-top to title of section 2. Don't apply both simultaneously as space will be double between them.

Try this and let me know if any query.
Hope This will help you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add css classes to the paragraphs, you can always try the first child selector which will allow you to add margin or padding to the first p of the document to add the extra space.

```
p:first-child {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp